# convert magento configurable product option dropdowns into selectable links or radio buttons

Tags: html, magento

I need to convert magento configurable product option dropdowns into selectable links or radio buttons styled like selectable links.. There are some paid themes that provide it but how to do it my shopper theme is not available anywhere..

what I want is something like this instead of default dropdowns..

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I said I have written simple javascript to convert the dropdowns into links. Script below converts the dropdowns into links and shows selected combination as well..

```
function replaceDropDowns() {
    jQuery('.product_attribute_option_link').remove();
    jQuery('#selected_combination').text('');
    jQuery(".super-attribute-select").each(function() {
        var drop_down = jQuery(this);
        drop_down.hide();
        drop_down.find("option[value!='']").each(function() {
            var option = jQuery(this);
            jQuery("<a>", { 
                    text: option.text(),
                    href: '#',
                    class: 'product_attribute_option_link',
                    'data-id': drop_down.attr('id'),
                    'data-name': drop_down.attr('name'),
                    'data-value': option.val(),
                    'data-label': option.text(),
                    click: function() { 
                        drop_down.val(option.val());
                        var obj = drop_down.get();
                        Event.observe(obj[0],'change',function(){});
                        fireEvent(obj[0],'change');
                        replaceDropDowns();
                        var selected_combination = [];
                        jQuery(".super-attribute-select").each(function() {
                            if(jQuery(this).val()) {
                                jQuery(".product_attribute_option_link[data-value="+jQuery(this).val()+"]").addClass('product_attribute_option_link_selected');
                                selected_combination.push(jQuery(this).find("option:selected").text());
                            }
                        });
                        jQuery.each(selected_combination, function(index, selection) {
                            jQuery('#selected_combination').append(selection);
                            if(index+1 < selected_combination.length)
                                jQuery('#selected_combination').append(" - ");
                        })
                        return false;
                    }
            }).appendTo(drop_down.parent());
        })
    });
}

jQuery(function() {
    replaceDropDowns();
})
```

Comment: Hi, Rajat, where should i place your code and does i need to do anything else? i put your code at the bottom on configurable.phtml file, it hides the dropdown but didn't showed attribute values. here is a screen shot 
http://awesomescreenshot.com/0d25xnsu8c

Comment: Hello Rajat, I am getting the below error when I click on the options, I am assuming that if we click on the options, the price should also change, Right ?

`Uncaught TypeError: Event.observe is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

You should create your template for configurable product.

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable translate="label" module="catalog">
    <reference name="product.info.options.wrapper">
        <reference name="product.info.options.wrapper"> 
             <action method="setTemplate">
                  <template>Your template file here</template>
         </action>
        </reference>
    </reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable>
```

And modify the code which copy from the original template file

```
design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml
```

Change these codes to what you need.

```
    <dd<?php if ($_attribute->decoratedIsLast){?> class="last"<?php }?>>
        <div class="input-box">
            <select name="super_attribute[<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>]" id="attribute<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>" class="required-entry super-attribute-select">
                <option><?php echo $this->__('Choose an Option...') ?></option>
              </select>
          </div>
    </dd>
```

Comment: Yes, but the js written for it (Backbone) will not work with the checkboxes.. I am working on changing the dropdown into links using js only..

Answer (score 0):

I improved the code a bit to add image latches to the options (your option image need to have attribute option name, be in gif format and be placed in /magento/media/optionimage/ :

```
    function replaceDropDowns() {
    jQuery('.product_attribute_option_link').remove();
    jQuery('#selected_combination').text('');
    jQuery(".super-attribute-select").each(function() {
        var drop_down = jQuery(this);
        drop_down.hide();
        drop_down.find("option[value!='']").each(function() {
            var option = jQuery(this);
            jQuery("<img>",{src:'/magento/media/optionimage/' + option.text() + ".gif"}).prependTo(
            jQuery("<div>", { 
                    text: option.text(),
                    href: '#',
                    class: 'product_attribute_option_link col-md-3',
                    'data-id': drop_down.attr('id'),
                    'data-name': drop_down.attr('name'),
                    'data-value': option.val(),
                    'data-label': option.text(),
                    click: function() { 
                        drop_down.val(option.val());
                        var obj = drop_down.get();
                        Event.observe(obj[0],'change',function(){});
                        fireEvent(obj[0],'change');
                        replaceDropDowns();
                        var selected_combination = [];
                        jQuery(".super-attribute-select").each(function() {
                            if(jQuery(this).val()) {
                                jQuery(".product_attribute_option_link[data-value="+jQuery(this).val()+"]").addClass('product_attribute_option_link_selected');
                                selected_combination.push(jQuery(this).find("option:selected").text());
                            }
                        });
                        jQuery.each(selected_combination, function(index, selection) {
                            jQuery('#selected_combination').append(selection);
                            if(index+1 < selected_combination.length)
                                jQuery('#selected_combination').append(" - ");
                        })
                        return false;
                    }
            }).appendTo(drop_down.parent()));

        })
    });
}

jQuery(function() {
    replaceDropDowns();
})
```